# What measures are used to protect private keys on credit card processing devices?

Tags: key-management, asymmetric

For example, a device that accepts credit card payment to update a store card.  These are usually embedded devices with a hard drive for permanent storage.  Would it not be possible for a hacker to steal one of these devices and do a binary copy of the hard drive of the device to another disk to extract the private keys?  What measures do manufacturers take to prevent this happening?